# is this the IE7 float bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

http://www.mapleboutique.com/_blog/maple_blog

can someone explain what's going on here? according to this link: http://austinmatzko.com/2007/07/25/internet-explorer-7-float-bug/ –I thought it made perfect sense. I had container elements with set heights causing the weird floating. But after spending an hour going through and essentially deleting any associated heights I still have the problem in IE7/windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `clear:right` from `.blog-post .post-body` to fix the heading overlap with the image and remove `zoom:1` from `.post-body a` to fix the text-wrap around the image.

The heading is also floated and cleared right but `clear:right` on the `post-body` seems to be causing IE to clear all the floats, even the heading.

The `zoom:1` seems to be clearing the image's intended float by giving the image layout.

As @Webars has already said, this layout is *overly floaty* and should be simplified and could be done without the need for `zoom` hacks. However in the meantime, the IE specific styles (`zoom` being one of them) could be added to a seperate stylesheet and included for IE only using [*Conditional comments*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: thank you. and yeah I'm going to write conditional comments for IE for now and work on cleaning up my code

Comment: Happy to help :-) I forgot to mention that I like the look of the site.